# Div not showing hover below

Tags: css

problem is that if i hover on Services it must show a div below which is displayed none by default but on hover it will display as a block , actually i dont know the css for that so pleas help me, i have this so please help me

**HTML:**

```
<section class="tmain">
    <div class="Button">
        SERVICES
    </div>
    <div class="Button">
        SERVICES
    </div>
</section>
<div class="ShowMe">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tmain{
            width:960px;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            background-color:#069;
            height:auto;
    }
    .Button{
            padding-bottom:40px;
            padding-top:40px;
            padding-left:30px;
            color:white;
            font-family:Agency FB;
            padding-right:30px;
            background-color:#309;
            font-size:36px;
            margin-left:10px;
            float:left;
    }
    .ShowMe{
            width:960px;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            background-color:#3C9;
            height:400px;
            display:none;
            position:relative;
            z-index:-1;
    }

    section.tmain:hover > .ShowMe{
        display:block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   section.tmain:hover + .ShowMe{
        display:block;
    }
```

Comment: but how can we show it as a drop down menu, when i hover on servvice it will show the div below,

Comment: @JhOnCena - well you got the css of the hover event, now just edit it accordingly , change the position, top, left, whatever you want